# How do I convert an angle to shadow offsets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a given angle to offset for a given shadow.

Is there some way you can do it with math, or is it impossible?

```
Text(
  'Hello, world!',
  style: TextStyle(
    shadows: <Shadow>[
      Shadow(
        offset: Offset(angeleToOffset(angelValue), angleToOffsets(angleValue)),
        blurRadius: 3.0,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
      ),

    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: check all `Offset` constructors

Comment: Can you include image that you are trying to get

Comment: Thanks pskink. I just checked one of the constructor, and it contains a named constructor that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked me to check one of the constructor of the Offset object. It has a named constructor that takes an angle in radian and a distance value.

```
Text(
  'Hello, world!',
  style: TextStyle(
    shadows: <Shadow>[
      Shadow(
        offset: Offset.fromDirection(angleInRadian, distance),
        blurRadius: 3.0,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
      ),

    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I chuckle at all the sin/cos/atan2 and fractional x y calculations that I see in CustomPainters, when most of that is already available in the protocols of Offset, Size, Alignment, and Rect.  Please review those if you're custom-painting!